# Symplectic vector fields form a Lie Algebra

Tags: vector-fields, symplectic-geometry

I am trying to prove that symplectic vector fields with the usual Lie bracket of vector fields form a Lie Algebra. Recall that a vector field $X$ on a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ is symplectic iff $\mathcal{L}_{X}\omega = 0$.

I can prove skew-symmetry, since by cartan homotopy formula $\mathcal{L}_{[X,Y]}\omega = d \mathcal{i}_{[X,Y]}\omega$, which equals $-d \mathcal{i}_{[Y,X]} \omega$ by skew-symmetry of $[\cdot,\cdot]$ and of $\mathcal{i}$, and this equals $-\mathcal{L}_{[Y,X]}\omega$.

I would like to ask how to prove Jacobi identity. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Since we give symplectic vector fields the same Jacobi-Lie bracket that the space of all vector fields is equipped with we can rephrase our question to be do the symplectic vector fields form a Lie subalgebra of the Lie algebra of vector fields. This means that all of the equations which are valid for vector fields are valid in this case as well.